# Proving this sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove the sequence $A_n = \frac{1}{n+1}+ \frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+ \frac{1}{2n}$ converges to a limit $a$ with $0 \leq a \leq 1$.

Some help would be greatly appreciated been stuck on this for a day or so now.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
Write $$A_n = \frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}+\frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)}+\dots+\frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{n}{n}\right)} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$$
and use theorems on [Riemann sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) to relate it to the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x}$.

Comment: we havent started Riemann Sums yet. Is there a way we can do this using epsilon proofs?

Answer (score 3):

If
$A_n
=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{k}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
A_{n+1}-A_n
&=\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2} \frac1{k}-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{k}\\
&=(\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n} \frac1{k}+\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2})
-(\frac1{n+1}+\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n} \frac1{k})\\
&=(\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2})-(\frac1{n+1})\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2n+2}\\
&<\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+2}\\
&=\frac12(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1})\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$A_{n+1}-A_{n}
=\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2n+2}
> 0
$,
the $A_n$ are increasing.

Summing,

$\begin{array}\\
A_{N+1}-A_1
&=\sum_{n=1}^N (A_{n+1}-A_n)\\
&< \sum_{n=1}^N \frac12(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1})\\
&=\frac12(1-\frac1{N+1})\\
&< \frac12
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$A_{N+1}
<A_1+\frac12
= 1
$.

Since the
$A_N$ are increasing and bounded,
they converge.

(I seem to have answered this
or a variation of this
a number of times recently.)

Comment: This looks vaguely familiar to what I was trying to attempt. I was stuck somewhere in the middle. Thanks @martycohen

Comment: This cancellation of common terms in sums occurs a lot. I have gotten (through practice) quite comfortable doing this. For a more complicated example, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165393/if-s-k-mn-sum-i-n1knm-frac1i-show-that-for-k-ge-2m1-s